# How do i print the values as i mentioned in the result of two array variables?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String[] firstName = {"Venkatesh", "Pushpalatha", "Bharath", "Sushsma", "Namratha",
        "Narendra", "Niveditha", "Neha", "Suresh", "Sahana", "Vishwanath", "Viabhavi"};

    String[] lastName = {"Shenoy", "Kamath", "Bhat"};

    for(int i=0;i<firstName.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<lastName.length;j++){

            System.out.println(firstName[i]+" "+lastName[j]);

        }
    }

}
```

I am pretty new to java and i want to print the result as follow

```
Venkatesh Shenoy
Pushpalatha Shenoy
Bharath Shenoy 
Sushsma Shenoy 
Namratha Kamath 
Suresh Bhat
and so on
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: How would you know which lastname goes with which firstname?

Comment: I want the result in the way i mentioned. I have a list with me where i have to print it as a result

Comment: Give a complete output.

Comment: is it like 4 shenoy 4 kamath and the rest to bhat ? and then loop back to top?

Comment: Yes. I want the full result like this Venkatesh Shenoy, Pusplatha Shenoy, Bharath Shenoy, Sushma Shenoy, Narendra Kamath, Namratha Kamath, Niveditha Kamath, Neha Kamath, Suresh Bhat, Sahana Bhat, Vishwanath Bhat, Viabhavi Bhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but if what you want is to print all the Shenoys first, then the Kamaths, etc, then all you should do is *switch the order of the loops*.

That is, iterate over the `lastName` array in the outer loop.

--

I see from your comments that you want 4 Shenoys, then 4 Kamaths, and the 4 of the last one.  In that case, there are many ways to do so. Here is one:

- Keep the outer loop for `firstName`.
- Remove the inner loop. Instead, have a variable `int j = i / 4;` and use that to get the last name.

This will output

```
Venkatesh Shenoy
Pusplatha Shenoy
Bharath Shenoy
Sushma Shenoy
Narendra Kamath
Namratha Kamath
Niveditha Kamath
Neha Kamath
Suresh Bhat
Sahana Bhat
Vishwanath Bhat
Viabhavi Bhat
```

Note that this will only work if you want to switch the last name every 4 first names. And it only works if `firstName.length <= lastName.length * 4`.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I have added a full result in the comment. Can you please check now

Comment: That result is different from what you commented in the other answer. Also, don't put "and so on". Be clear. What's the full output?

Comment: Ok got it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok. My last edit should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will change the `lastname` in every 4 counts of `firstname`.

```
String[] firstName = { "Venkatesh", "Pushpalatha", "Bharath", "Sushsma", "Namratha", "Narendra", "Niveditha",
            "Neha", "Suresh", "Sahana", "Vishwanath", "Viabhavi" };
    String[] lastName = { "Shenoy", "Kamath", "Bhat" };
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstName.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(firstName[i] + " " + lastName[j]);
        if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
            j++;
        }
    }
```